SQL that works fine when read in OPENROWSET fails when the same code is a string in T-SQL
I'm writing some basic testing code to try out a couple of ways to address UPDATE performance. I made 10000 lines of UPDATES and saved that to a textfile. It's about 3 MB in total. An example of the lines in the file is:
UPDATE Extras SET [Name]='Note',[Table]='Details',
[Row]=5954211,[Value]='No fee for this customer',
[Type]='String' WHERE [Key]=355 AND [ProjKey]=4

I then opened that text file in SMS and ran it, and it takes about 3 seconds. I then used this code:
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\the file.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS data
)
EXEC sp_executsql @sql

As I hoped, this ran much faster, about three times. But it has the downside that it needs a file. So I then re-wrote the UPDATE file to escape the quotes on strings:
UPDATE Extras SET [Name]=''Note'',[Table]=''Details'',
[Row]=5954211,[Value]=''No fee for this customer'',
[Type]=''String'' WHERE [Key]=355 AND [ProjKey]=4

And removed the OPENROWSET and simply put the resulting string in as a constant:
SET @sql='UPDATE...'

SMS displays this correctly, the UPDATEs are a big red string and the DECLARE, SET and EXEC are seen as commands.
This does not run, you get random errors about syntax in lines that are clearly fine. Removing all the lines after a point about 10 lines above the error allows it to run without error. As does removing all the lines above this point and running the next batch.
Now I am aware that there is an 8000 character limit in strings fed to EXEC, but this error occurs ~800k, and not at all when I use OPENROWSET. I'm well below the size limit for a varchar(max). When I tried clipping out various parts, it always happened around the 2000 line mark. But I am unaware of any limits that might apply around this size.
Can anyone offer some insight here?

It really feels like a limit on the client side (SSMS in this case) but the only thing I can find that limits the length of TSQL being submitted is the server max of 65536*<network packet size> which is typically well over 200MB, and you would have hit it with OPENROWSET. I have to ask though, why not just shovel this data into a table and then join to do your update instead of submitting thousands of update statements?

Non-expert here... A search for "ssms big script" yielded this question and this referenced question, among others. The problem might be memory issues or network packet limitations causing script truncation, but I'm surprised that you are not getting a more generalized error instead of a syntax error. Although the pages are old, your problem might be similar. Using the suggested alternatives such as sqlcmd may work for you.

As a complete change of direction, it might be better to just write your data (keys and values) to a CSV file that you could then load into a staging table. Your script could then be optimized to apply changes either (1) one row at a time, (2) all at once, or (3) in batches of N rows - chosen based on best performance.  Often the third option strikes a nice balance between performance, lock duration, and the ability to recover from errors.

I fully agree: you are going down the wrong path in the first place. Giant SQL scripts are generally not necessary with SQL Server, because it has Table Valued Parameters, temp tables and bulk inserts, as well as native backup/restore, both cases where MySQL and SQLite  resort to giant SQL files. You should use the proper method, rather than trying to port over code and ideas from another system.

@TN- that is the ultimate goal, but I'm doing this exercise to prove it is worthwhile. This is a customer database we wish not to "pollute" with too many new tables. I'm also looking at reasonable ways to build it all using temps, but I'm not there yet.

Ok, following some of the links above I found that this occurs around the 2000 line mark no matter what the lines are. It is also NOT just in SSMS, I get the same thing if I send it in using a DbCommand. Work continues...
